# CSS Two Column layout and tables issue in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

Hi I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="CONTENT">
    <div id="SIDEBAR"></div>
    <div id="MAIN">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div><label><span><a><span>My Label</span></a></span></label><span class="colon">:</span></div></td>
        <td>hsadnsdjfjkasdfhkjadshfjkahsdkfjhasdjkfhjkasdhfjkaf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <div><label><span><a><span>My Label with a really long title</span></a></span><span class="colon">:</span></div></label>
       </td>
               <td>hsadnsdjfjkasdfhkjadshfjkahsdkfjhasdjkfhjkasdhfjkaf</td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
         <td>       
           <div><label><span><a><span>My Label</span></a></span><span class="colon">:</span></div></label>
</td>
    <td><input value="hsadnsdjfjkasdfhkjadshfjkahsdkfjhasdjkfhjkasdhfjkaf" /></td>

    </tr>


            </table>
       </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
#CONTENT{
    font-size: 87%;
    padding: 5px;
}
#SIDEBAR{
    width: 24em; float: left; margin-right: 0.5%;height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#MAIN {
    /*margin-left: 25em;*/
    border: 1px solid purple;float:right;
}

table div{
     position:relative;
}

.colon {
     position: absolute;
    right:0;
}

label {
    margin-right: .4em;
}
```

In IE7 if you resize the window and make it thinner the table seems to move down the page. I would like to simply show a scrollbar like IE9 and FF.

Live Example : http://jsfiddle.net/aJsg2/19/

Comment: While in our firm we have to support IE7 and I am one of those who like to push for modern browsers but sometimes you hands are just tied behind ones back.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a min-width on the CONTENT in the stylesheet to be whatever the minimum width of the sidebar + main content is.

Comment: I want the MAIN content to be dynamic so I dont know what the width would be.Also doesn't min-width not work properly with IE6+7?